# Automation Error "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I'm creating vba sub in excel to automate getting data from the website. But I'm stuck with clicking an element. I kept receiving the error Run-time error -02147417848 (80010108). I don't know if I had missed something. I already tried using its id and name but it's just the same.

```
Sub audit()
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://samplesite.com"
End With
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
ie.document.getElementsByClassName("xxxxxxx")(0).Click // usually the error is here

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess, maybe some scripts are still working after 5 seconds? Give it more time or try to simulate scrolling down to fire all scripts (it worked for me in some cases).

Comment: When error raises, press debug, type in immediate window `? TypeName(ie)`, and post the output. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47084865/2165759) also.