# Trying to scrape data off website

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the address and telephone number from a website. The HTML of the webpage is shown below:

```html
<p class="profileText">
                    <span id="ctl00_PageWrapper_ContentAndSidebar_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextContent_lblExhibitorDetails" class="editorLabel">Checkout.com<br>32 Wigmore Street<br>London<br>W1U 2RP<br>Tel. 0207 323 3888<br></span>
                </p>
```

Using this code:

```
Sub Demo()
 Dim URL As String
 Dim ieDoc As Object
 Dim cel As Range

 For Each cel In Range("G2", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
URL = cel.Value
With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    .Visible = False
    .Navigate URL

    Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set ieDoc = .Document
    cel.Offset(, 1).Value = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("profileText")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    .Quit
End With
Next cel
End Sub
```

But i am having no joy. Can anyone assist me please?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I am getting a run time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set, with the line beginning cel.Offset highlighted yellow.

Comment: is ieDoc setting correctly in the line before?

Comment: What is the URL? I guess you need wait until the target elements are ready, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47084865/2165759).

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging your code? With the many available tools in the IDE?

Comment: `ieDoc.getElementById("ctl00_PageWrapper_ContentAndSidebar_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextContent_lblExhibitorDetails")` is more direct

Comment: I am now getting no error, but the data off the webpage isnt being copied into the cell on the spreadsheet.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas? @TimWilliams

Comment: "I am now getting no error" - after doing what exactly?

Comment: Sorry @TimWilliams. When I run the macro I now no longer get an error, but the data is not being copied into the relevant cells.

Answer (score 2):

Without the actual urls it is hard to provide you with any solution. However, give it a try:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDoc As HTMLDocument, cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("G2", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        With IE
            .Visible = False
            .navigate cel
            Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Set ieDoc = .document
            r = r + 1: Cells(r, 2) = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("editorLabel")(0).innerText
        End With
    Next cel
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft Html Object Library
```

How come you encounter any error when I'm having results. It's a tester:

```
Sub Data_scraper()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim ieDoc As HTMLDocument

    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://www.retailbusinesstechnologyexpo.com/exhibitor-profile/citizen-systems-europe"
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set ieDoc = .document
        MsgBox ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("editorLabel")(0).innerText
    End With
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Topto, I will try it now. The URL is http://www.retailbusinesstechnologyexpo.com/exhibitor-profile/citizen-systems-europe

Comment: I am getting a runtime error '91' and when clicking on debug this line is highlighted yellow  r = r + 1: Cells(r, 2) = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("profileText")(0).getElementsByClassName("editorLabel")(0).innerText

Comment: Run the tester and see what you get. By the way, have you added those two references?

Comment: Aha the tester worked, thank you very very much! Just need to change it so it copies into a cell as opposed to a msgbox, so I can run it on multiples.

Comment: If it fixes the issue, don't forget to mark this as an answer by ticking the grayed out checkmark next to my answer. Thanks.